# Parse large CSV into mysql db

Tags: php, csv, kohana

I want to parse very large csv into mysql using php. My idea is to make it with executing 4-5 times the request which will paste data into mysql, after each iteration request should start from rows which has not been pasted yet (with one request iteration script can cover 400 rows). But I don't know to skip rows in csv, which has been already pasted into database. Maybe I should check number of rows in the table then define some variable with this number and make iteration according on it. But I don't know how to operate with csv using foreach, I only have code with "while" from example. 
Here is my current code:

```
public function action_index(){

    if(($handle = fopen('data_wpic.csv', 'r')) !== false)
    {
        $header = fgetcsv($handle);

        while(($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false)
        {


            $model = ORM::factory('Drug');

            $image_path = $data[18];
            if(strlen($image_path) > 5) {
                $path= 'drug_images/' . $image_path;

                $image = ORM::factory('Image')->remote($path);
                if ($image) {
                    $model->image_id = $image;
                    unlink($path);
                }
            }

            $model->drugGenericName = $data[17];
            $model->drugForm = $data[4];
            $model->drugProperties = $data[7];
            $model->drugIndication = $data[2];
            $model->drugDosage = $data[13];
            $model->drugSide = $data[11];
            $model->drugContrIndication = $data[12];
            $model->drugInteractions = $data[15];
            $model->drugSpecial = $data[0];
            $model->drugExpiry = $data[3];
            $model->drugRealCondition = $data[8];
            $model->tradeName = $data[16];

            $model->save();

            unset($data);

        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

}
```

I have limited web hosting, thats why I try to solve this routine
If someone knows better aproach - I will be glad to hear him

Comment: load the whole csv into a temp table, then you can do your dupe checking in the db.

Comment: @MarcB how to do it?

Comment: Can you use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to load the table directly from the CSV? You can then use the `IGNORE` option to skip duplicates.

Comment: Or write a minion task for this.